# Отправка email без авторизации и без smtp сервера на C#

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер все, у меня такой вопрос, может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким вопросом или может есть пример. В общем я хочу отправить email оповещение без авторизации на почте, т.е. чтобы не хранить сам пароль в исполняемом файле.
Так же к оповещению цепляется файл приглашения.
Вот,спасибо заранее за ответы;)

Comment: спам-бота программируете?

Comment: нет, я сделал программку помощник удаленного подключения.
не люблю спам!!!! даже ненавижу, так что это дял более полезных целей.

Answer (score 2):

вообще, если это не «[открытый релей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)», то без авторизации *smtp-сервер* примет почту только для обслуживаемых им доменов.

если отправляемая вами почта удовлетворяет данному условию (или вы используете «открытый релей»), то можно использовать стандартный класс `smtpclient`.

как подсказывает @PashaPash в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/207515/436626?noredirect=1#comment455693_436626), в документации написано:

[Если для свойства `UseDefaultCredentials` задано значение `false` и свойство `Credentials` не задано, то почта будет отправлена на сервер анонимно.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: это просто кастомная реализация smtp client (==велосипед), а не способ отправить почту без использования smtp server.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: @PashaPash, да, насколько я вижу, там нет ничего про запрос mx-записей для домена получателя и выбор сервера из списка, но всё остальное, вроде бы, реализовано. вообще я, конечно зря полез в «чужое хозяйство», разгребая [неотвеченный вопросы](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/808/178576), просто вопрос показался интересным. если у вас есть пример реализации более функционального «велосипеда», то поделитесь, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ixSci, вообще-то ссылка ведёт на ответ на [so], а уже из этого ответа взята вторая ссылка — на статью. вы считаете, что стоило ещё добавить «копипаст» кода из этой статьи?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, я полагаю, что нужно. Иначе Ваш ответ выглядит как набор ссылок и по существу ответом не является. На мой взгляд ссылки должны вести на дополнение к ответу, а не быть самим ответом.

Comment: @ixSci, согласен. «скопипастил» код из статьи.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin в smtp протокол пересылки писем между серверами и протокол обычной отправки письма совпадают. т.е. можно весь код из примера выкинуть и заменить на обычный SmtpClient.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin обычно smtp сервер принимает два типа сообщений. Первые - в которых from принадлежит его домену, с авторизацией. Вторые - те, в который to принадлежит его домену, без авторизации. Т.е. для отправки письма, например, to vasil@example.com, можно просто подключится обычным SmtpClient к серверу из MX example.com и отправить письмо с любым from, и to vasil@example.com. А велосипед из поста - не нужен.

Comment: @PashaPash *заменить на обычный SmtpClient* — возможно. но я сходу не нашёл примера использования класса smptclient **без использования авторизации** и сделал предположение, что в этот *образцовый* класс авторизация «забита гвоздями».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin `UseDefaultCredentials = false`. [Если для свойства UseDefaultCredentials задано значение false и свойство Credentials не задано, то почта будет отправлена на сервер анонимно.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.usedefaultcredentials(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо за ссылку. значит, «велосипед» точно излишен. я исправил ответ.